# Checking if object is in list

Tags: java

Using the `contains` method I'm checking to see if an object is in an arraylist, if it's not then I add it else I want to increment the count.

```
        if (!data.contains(d)) {
            data.add(d);
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++) {
                if (data.get(j).equals(d)) {
                    data.get(j).incrementCount();
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm looking at the code I've written and it looks wasteful, having to loop through the arraylist multiple times, I was thinking about using booleans but was wondering if there is any other way.

Comment: Not sure how to write in Java, but couldn't you just increase the count within a `try..catch` statement, and if it fails add it (as it didn't find it already)?

Comment: Please provide more context. What is `d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)):

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

So, you can do this:

```
int index = data.indexOf(d);
if (index == -1) {
    data.add(d);
}
else {
    data[index].incrementCount();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh, I see! I updated the answer! I hope it helps!